# Regular Expression matches in online testing but not in javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, regex

My regular expression should find and remove all words beginning with `foo-`. The regular expression works in an online regex http://regexr.com/3gafi but fails in my javascript.

Whats going wrong?

```js
$('[class*="foo-"]').each(function(index, ele) {

 ele.className = ele.className.replace(/(foo-.*( |\0))/g, '');
  console.log(ele.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo-abc img-responsive"></div>

<div class="foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc "></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\bfoo-.*?(?= |$)` works. You'll want to make sure it removes only words beginning with foo and nothing else. The lookahead helps with that.

```js
$('[class*="foo-"]').each(function(index, ele) {

 ele.className = ele.className.replace(/(\bfoo-.*?(?= |$))/g, '');
  console.log(ele.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo-abc img-responsive"></div>

<div class="foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc "></div>
```

I assumed you want to retain `img-responsive`. If not, remove the lookahead, and convert the non-greedy match to a greedy one (with `*`).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[class*="foo-"]').each(function(index, ele) {

 ele.className = ele.className.replace(/(foo-.*( |\0)?)/g, '');
  console.log(ele.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo-abc img-responsive"></div>

<div class="foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc"></div>

<div class=" foo-abc "></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression in your example does not work for the replacement. Try using the following - `/(foo-[^ "]+ ?)/g`